# How to convert java KeyStore to PKCS7 .p7b file?

Tags: java, security, ssl, keystore, jks

[Convert X509 to PKCS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16014157/how-to-convert-x509-certificate-into-pkcs7-using-bouncycastle)

[Create PKCS7 from keystore](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/13910/pkcs7-encoding-in-java-without-external-libs-like-bouncycastle-etc)

I have tried both the answers above but I feel these do not suit my need since Based on the below link I can summarize that PKCS7 is used for two purposes,

1. Creating signatures, digest etc CMS(Crytographic message syntax)
2. A container for certificates

[Based on this I summarized](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/73156/whats-the-difference-between-x-509-and-pkcs7-certificate)

My need is more of point no.2. I just want to create a .p7b file using all the certificates that I have in a KeyStore object. Since PKCS7 cannot contain private key. The above two answers generate a signature and what not. Am I missing something? is that the way to go ahead or is there another way?

I can extract certs from a .p7b file using

```
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream( "cert.pkcs7" );
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance( "X.509" );
Iterator i = cf.generateCertificates( is ).iterator();
while ( i.hasNext() ) 
{
   Certificate c = (Certificate)i.next();
   System.out.println(Base64.getEncoder.encodeToString(c.getEncoded());
}
```

**I am asking how to do the reverse, i.e create a .p7b file from `Certificate[]` or Java `KeyStore`**

Okay I found the solution:

[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45278296/convert-pem-to-pkcs7-java) In this we can create what I exactly asked for but I still get the signed data which is generated. I don't want that. A simple .p7b package which I already have has no signerInfo will the .p7b created by this solution have it?

Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: You DO want a SignedData. A **p7b/p7c IS a SignedData** with no (or dummy) ContentInfo and no SignerInfo's, only certs (or possibly CRLs, but you won't get any CRLs from a Java keystore). That's exactly what #45278296 does. Notice it does NOT have a SignerInfoGenerator like #16014157 or a SignerInfo like security #13910.

Comment: Alright. Thank you for clearing my doubt. So does that mean pkcs7 is not meant for just a container of certificates? I mean it can be used that way but why would anyone choose PKCS7 as a container of certs when other formats exist specifically for that purpose.

Comment: PKCS7 and its successor CMS (rfcs 2630 3369 3370 5652 et rel) are multi-purpose, almost all-purpose, formats used for many things. Probably best known, CMS is used for S/MIME secure email. p7b/p7c is one particular use, for a set of cert(s) and/or CRL(s). Except 'PKIpath', which is not really a format but the lack of one, the only theoretical alternative I know is PKCS12, which _as implemented_ usually does not support cert(s) alone without privatekey (and not CRL(s) at all). What other standards are you referring to? ...

Comment: ... See also https://serverfault.com/questions/9708/what-is-a-pem-file-and-how-does-it-differ-from-other-openssl-generated-key-file https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/94797/is-there-an-official-standard-and-or-name-for-pem-certificate-bundles https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/80410/sign-pkcs7-and-verify-pkcs7-signature-with-openssl https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/73156/whats-the-difference-between-x-509-and-pkcs7-certificate -- and that last reminded me of an alternative: Java `CertPath.getEncoded()` _creates_ a p7-certs-only.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thank you. I was referring to PKCS12 and one more specific to java called JKS(Java KeyStore) format. Actually I have seen both of them supporting to store only certs without private key also. Hence the question why would anyone use PKCS7 to store just certs when other formats are available.  Also thank you for the resources. Could you write an answer so that I can accept it? or should I write it?

Comment: _In Java_ (which is a small part of the computer world) JKS and also less-used JCEKS support lone certs, but nothing else supports those formats and they are not standards at all. In fact in Java 9 up keytool warns they are 'proprietary' and recommends you switch to PKCS12 -- which _as implemented in Java 8+_ does support lone certs (note my comment was PKCS12 'as implemented **usually**') and this also is often not interoperable. Since both your solution and mine are already posted I don't see any benefit to a dup but feel free to do so if you want.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thank you for clearing my doubts. I will add an answer just in case any wandering soul like me can access the knowledge that you have shared. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45278296/convert-pem-to-pkcs7-java):

code:

```
//Export a certificate list to PKCS#7
public static byte[] exportCertificatesAsPkcs7(X509Certificate certs[]) throws Exception {

    List certList = new ArrayList();
    for (X509Certificate certificate: certs){
        certList.add(new X509CertificateHolder(certificate.getEncoded()));
    }
    Store certStore = new JcaCertStore(certList);

    CMSProcessableByteArray msg = new CMSProcessableByteArray("Hello World".getBytes());
    CMSSignedDataGenerator    gen = new CMSSignedDataGenerator(); 
    gen.addCertificates(certStore);
    CMSSignedData data = gen.generate(msg, "BC"); 
    return data.getEncoded();

}
```

Useful links related to PKCS7:

[Convert X509 to PKCS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16014157/how-to-convert-x509-certificate-into-pkcs7-using-bouncycastle)

[Create PKCS7 from keystore](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/13910/pkcs7-encoding-in-java-without-external-libs-like-bouncycastle-etc)